# Incorrectly received announcer badge

Tags: support

I apparently just [received the Announcer badge](https://superuser.com/help/badges/64/announcer?userid=46972) for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/308135/how-can-i-improve-font-appearance-in-google-chrome).

As far as I can tell, I've never seen that question before now; I certainly didn't ask it, and didn't write/edit any answers on it (supporting evidence that I've never seen it before).

Did I receive this badge incorrectly?

Did someone share the link to that question and accidentally embed my user ID inside instead of their own (typo?)

Comment: You commented on the accepted answer. "This answer explains how to do it on XP -- there's no "ClearType" in Start or in the Control Panel. [How can I improve font appearance in google chrome?](//superuser.com/a/441694)"

Comment: *Did I receive this badge incorrectly?*  - You shared a link to one the question's answers in a comment.  So you were awarded the badge correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/309841/19943):

> This answer explains how to do it on XP -- there's no "ClearType" in Start or in the Control Panel. http://superuser.com/a/441694/46972

links to [another answer on the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/308135/how-can-i-improve-font-appearance-in-google-chrome/441694#441694)

So yes, you were awarded it correctly.